# Getting this while reading response "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: android, web-services, exception

I am calling a Url by using below mentioned method and getting this response

> "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

But when I call this url by using get method in POSTMAN I am getting the response

> "ok" and "user name is not valid".

Will you please tell me what i have done wrong or is this server error ?

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("http://www.myvirtualmd.net/Apps/Controller/securityController.aspx?type=RESET_PASSWORD&info=dsadas"));
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                entity.getContentLength();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader =
                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
                    String line = "";

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }


                System.out.println("finalResult " + sb.toString());
```

Comment: it is Server Side issue .... might be related to database ...equivalent to nullpointre

Comment: are you sure because this api is working properly in iphone but not in android ?

Comment: yes debug your server code while calling this .....

Comment: okay Thanku so much,I debugged it many time i always got this in my entity.

Comment: what is your response from server side post here for better understanding

Comment: Please don't use DefaultHttpClient as it is deprecated. Either use HttpsURLConnection or a networking library, such as Retrofit or Volley.

Comment: @amit "ok" and "user name is not valid", if calling from PostMan

Comment: @Eran I tried it by using that too, but getting same issue

Comment: @Chirag what you input and what you output get from Response .... Post here .We have not more time to teach you again and again Things ...

Comment: @amit I already mentioned in above  what i am giving input and what i am getting response Please check the url , Its a get method not a post method .

Answer (score 0):

There can be come html tags in response of Api you can check it by RAW response from Postman.